# Writing user input from angular 4 to mysql through node.js

Tags: mysql, node.js, database, angular

What i'm trying to achieve is to send user input from a textbox, send that data to node.js after the enter button is clicked, which then writes that value into my specified mysql table. I just need to be able to post into the database not read back. At this point I just want the user to be able to enter 1 value (so page doesn't have to go back to allow user to enter more then 1 value). Thank you in advance.

**Hero-form.component.html**

```
<div class="container">
  <div [hidden]="submitted">
    <h1>Hero Form</h1>
    <form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()" #heroForm="ngForm">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="name">Name</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name"
               required
               [(ngModel)]="model.name" name="name"
               #name="ngModel">
        <div [hidden]="name.valid || name.pristine"
             class="alert alert-danger">
          Name is required
        </div>
      </div>

      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" [disabled]="!heroForm.form.valid">Submit</button>
    </form>
  </div>

  <div [hidden]="!submitted">
    <h2>You submitted the following:</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-xs-3">Name</div>
      <div class="col-xs-9  pull-left">{{ model.name }}</div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <button class="btn btn-primary" (click)="submitted=false">Edit</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Hero-form.component.ts**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { HttpClient, HttpHeaders } from '@angular/common/http';
import { Hero } from '../recipe';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { catchError, map, tap } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-hero-form',
  templateUrl: './hero-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./hero-form.component.css']
})
export class HeroFormComponent implements OnInit {

  private heroesUrl = 'http://localhost:8081';

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }
powers = ['Really Smart', 'Super Flexible',
            'Super Hot', 'Weather Changer'];

  model = new Hero(18, 'Dr IQ');

  submitted = false;

onSubmit(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero>{
  return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero)
}

  /*onSubmit(hero: Hero): Observable<Hero> { 
    return this.http.post<Hero>(this.heroesUrl, hero, httpOptions).pipe(
      tap((hero: Hero) => this.log(`added hero w/ id=${hero.id}`)),
      catchError(this.handleError<Hero>('addHero'))
    ); 
  }*/

  newHero() {
    this.model = new Hero(42, '');
  }
}
```

**App.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule }   from '@angular/forms';

import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { HeroFormComponent } from './hero-form/hero-form.component';


import { HttpClientModule } from '@angular/common/http';

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    FormsModule,
    HttpClientModule
  ],
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    HeroFormComponent
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**database.js**

```
var express    = require('express');
var app        = express();
var mysql      = require('mysql');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: false}));
//app.use(express.json());
//app.use(express.urlencoded());
//app.use(app.router);
app.use(express.static('public'));

var connection = mysql.createConnection({

  host     : 'localhost',
  user     : 'root',
  password : '1234',
  database : 'mydb' 

});

connection.connect();

// Put 
app.post('/heroes', function(req, res){
// console.log('read after this');
connection.query("INSERT INTO heroes (herolist) VALUES ?", function(err, result){
    console.log(res);
    if(err) {
       // console.log("Error in database for put");
    } else {
       // console.log("Added successfully");
        }

        })
    })


app.listen(8081, function () {
    console.log('Example app listening on port 8081');
    });
```

Comment: There's no question here, just a statement of what you hope to build

Comment: My question is how do I pass the value from the textbox to interact with the node.js code? So angular -> node.js